# perl regex not start of string

Tags: regex, perl

I can't figure this out looking at the documentation.

I want to match something that appears everywhere except the start of the string

```
"hello world hello hello" =~ m/^hello/
```

Would match the first hello

What I want it NOT^, so match the second and third hello but not the first

Is that possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would do:

```
/(?<=.)hello/sg
```

Comment: +1. Alternatively: `/(?!^)hello/g`, which would also work under JavaScript.

Comment: @ikegami could you explain how this regex works? what keywords should I search for to understand what you wrote?

Comment: @con, `hello`, preceded by a something matching `.`, which is to say any character (since `s`) is used. Regex are documented in perlre, and the match operator is documented in perlop.